# Permission denied while trying to read file with 777 on Android

Tags: android, android-file

I have a file in /data/data:

```
# ls -la /data/data/com.package/files/file.json
-rwxrwxrwx u0_a104  u0_a104
```

I'm trying to read it from different UID (1000, system UID):

```
new FileInputStream(FILE)
```

and getting "EACCES (Permission denied)".

API level is 21.

Why, if I've set 777 rights on it?

UPD. I can read the file from adb with uid = 2000 (not root).

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: @SanyamJain yes, but I need to open it as java.File.

Comment: is your app a system app?

Comment: I'm reading it from Xposed module, it runs with system uid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found out that problem was in SELinux. After disabling SELinux everything is OK.

Answer (score 3):

This is application level permission, you can't access using right, If your device rooted then you can able to use it otherwise you can't.

Comment: Isn't it handled just by default Linux filesystems permissions?

Comment: adb is working same like root device. that's why you can able access

Comment: Finally, that was SELinux behaviour.